# How to get ContourPlot3D to run involving elliptic functions?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, special-functions

I need to plot zeroes of a function of three variables that involves elliptic functions. For example, I have

```
f[x_, t_, v_] := -(Cos[t] JacobiDN[(2 x  
EllipticK[InverseEllipticNomeQ[\[ExponentialE]^-\[Pi]^2/Log[(5 + 
Sin[t] + Sqrt[-(2 + Cos[t])^2 + (5 + Sin[t])^2])/(5 + Sin[t] - 
Sqrt[-(2 + Cos[t])^2 + (5 + Sin[t])^2])]]])/Log[(5 + Sin[t] + 
Sqrt[-(2 + Cos[t])^2 + (5 + Sin[t])^2])/(5 + Sin[t] - Sqrt[-(2 + 
Cos[t])^2 + (5 + Sin[t])^2])], InverseEllipticNomeQ[\[ExponentialE]^-
\[Pi]^2/Log[(5 + Sin[t] + Sqrt[-(2 + Cos[t])^2 + (5 + Sin[t])^2])/(5 
+ Sin[t] - Sqrt[-(2 + Cos[t])^2 + (5 + Sin[t])^2])]]]^2)/v 

ContourPlot3D[f[x, t, v] == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {t, -2, 2}, {v, 5, 10}]
```

But Mathematica is unable to run it. (My real function is actually much more complicated, the above is just a similar example). I am using Mathematica 6. My processor is 2.1GHz and 3.00Gb RAM.

What could I do to get the code to run? Thanks.

Comment: A few tips: try setting `MaxRecursion -> 0` and `PlotPoints` to a modestly-sized value, just for exploration; and, try to compute things only once (thus, use `With[]`, `Module[]`, etc.).

Comment: When you say "unable to run it" do you mean that you get no result, the input is returned, it just churns, you get errors...?

Comment: One more thing: `EllipticK[InverseEllipticNomeQ[q]] == π EllipticTheta[3, 0, q]^2/2`

Comment: As pointed out, you're likely running afoul of the recursion algorithm, so its worthwhile to look at `ListContourPlot3D`, too. Doing so shows that the function has two sheets near $t \pm 2$, so the recursion algorithm is very likely having issues finding the initial points.

Comment: It just churns @MarcoB

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to check the recursion algorithm. I actually succeeded in running my original code (it took 20 minutes). I will try to my other (more complicated) function, bearing your comments in mind @J.M.

Comment: Also, you might want to look up `ModularLambda[]`.